# JavaFXSceneBuilder1.1 not starting in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, javafx-2, netbeans-7

JavaFXSceneBuilder1.1 does not start on my Ubuntu Linux box.

Running it with strace gives

```
[...]
_llseek(3, 58278358, [58278358], SEEK_SET) = 0
read(3, "PK\3\4\n\0\0\0\0\0j\26AB\327\343\f!\242\0\0\0\242\0\0\0\36\0\0\0", 30) = 30
_llseek(3, 58278418, [58278418], SEEK_SET) = 0
read(3, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0003\0\t\1\0\nSourceFile\1\0\tinterr"..., 162) = 162
gettimeofday({1361821505, 463824}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 463860}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 463896}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 463932}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 463968}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464003}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464068}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464106}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464142}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464183}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464222}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464309}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1361821505, 464346}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x835beac, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL
```

then it hangs.

Strangely when I start it with

```
sudo ./JavaFXSceneBuilder1.1
```

everything seems to work without problems.

Linux is 3.2.0-38-generic-pae #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:39:51 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

SceneBuilder is javafx_scenebuilder-1_1-beta-b21-linux-i586-14_feb_2013

sudo is a non-option for me, not only because it doesn't integrate with Netbeans 7.3, but also for security reasons.

Comment: Is the binary owned by root?

Comment: no, none of the files in any directory is owned by root

Comment: When you run as user, does it spawn threads?  What are those threads doing?  Try a: ps -efL|grep JavaFXSceneBuilder1.1

Comment: yes, it spawns 17 threads, but those threads don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a visually impaired person you ain't gonna like my answer:

To make it render properly I had to disable "Assistive Technologies".

In GNOME 2, System-> Preferences-> Assistive Technologies-> Enable assistive technologies set to disable and log out.